# Today widget doesn't update from TestFlight / Enterprise distribution

Tags: ios8, testflight, ios8-today-widget, hockeyapp

I have an app that contains a Today Widget and it's working fine during debug as well as the first version distributed using TestFlight & HockeyApp.

The problem occurs when the user updates to a newer build through their service. The widget seems to just show the snapshot and never actually initializes (I print out logs when it gets to certain parts of my view controller but I'm not seeing those).

To fix this problem the user will have to restart their device or delete and install the app again.

Does anyone know of this issue and/or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same issue using OTA installation (Testflight web, HockeyApp) but it seems to work fine distributing through the new Apple Testflight app.

I would suggest filing a radar ticket to Apple if you plan to continue distributing apps with widgets through OTA methods. Personally I've just switched over to using the new Apple Testflight app to distribute my betas.